# How to increment date in arrayformula sumifs in google sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have adapted a formula from another post and it works, yet I need to increment the formula down hundreds of rows, but I cannot figure out how to get the dates to increase.

I have a Google Form that sends data to its spreadsheet. There may be several entries per date and I want the data to be summed on the 2nd sheet before I graph it.

```
Data
 A                     B
6/3/2016 06:06:00      2
6/3/2016 11:06:00      2
6/4/2016 07:05:00      1
6/4/2016 09:10:00      5

Result
 A   B
6/3  4
6/4  

B2 =ArrayFormula(SUM(If((Data!A$2:A<DATE(2016,6,5))*(Data!A$2:A>DATE(2016,6,4)),Data!B$2:B)))
```

I will have dates that run the entire year, so I need an easy way to increment the dates. Also, if you have a way to grab data from the exact date needed, that would be nice too (instead of giving the date range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query formula may work better in this example, such as:

`=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(TRUNC('Form responses 1'!A2:A)),'Form responses 1'!B2:B},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 >0 group by Col1 label Col1'Date' format Col1 'mm-dd'")`

Amend the sheet name and ranges as appropriate

Comment: Hi Chris, your example does work very well. Thank you! I was even able to figure out how to add additional columns into the formula to produce sums in Col3 and a count of daily submissions in Col4, yet I may have more to add down the line. However, I think I want a cutoff date. I don't want this form to collect or sum any submissions after 7/31/2016. Is there a way to add that into your query example? If not, please refer to my original question of incrementing the formula for the individual column B. Also, is there a way to have the query align-center my columns automatically?

Comment: Or maybe I will have to figure out how to put that as code for the Google form in its script editor?

Comment: to limit query by date, add this into where clause: `...where Col1 >= date '" & TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "' label...`   Put your date in cell A1. Look for [more info here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where)